# File does not exist though the path seems right

Tags: php, path, file-exists

I can't figure out why file_exists() don't find my file though the path seem right.

Here is my script :

```
if($_POST['delete-avatar'] == 'on') {
  $q = execute_query("SELECT avatar FROM gj_customers WHERE id_customer = '$_GET[id]'");
  $customer = $q->fetch_assoc();
  $img_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . WEBSITE_ROOT . $customer['avatar'];
  var_dump($img_path);

  if(!empty($customer['avatar'])  && file_exists($img_path)){
    unlink($img_path);
  }
}
```

I'm on MAMP, my website is in htdocs/gamejutsu/www/ , WEBSITE_ROOT contains '/gamejutsu/www/' and avatars are in img/avatars/ .

var_dump on $img_path returns me : /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gamejutsu/www/img/avatars/Sonik_avatar.jpg.

If I go on localhost:8888/gamejutsu/www/img/avatars/Sonik_avatar.jpg the image is displayed.

I never enter in the if bloc. If I remove the file_exists test I have a warning : unlink(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gamejutsu/www/img/avatars/Sonik_avatar.jpg): No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gamejutsu/www/admin/members.php on line 67

I'm pretty sure i'm missing something but everything seems ok for me and I use the same method somewhere else on my website without any problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is complicated debug your application without access but you can try what return realpath();

```
var_dump(realpath($img_path))
```

If returns null file doesn't exists or your application haven't acces to it.

Try open your console and this command:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gamejutsu/www/img/avatars/
```

If you have error you have bad path and must manualy check it (easiest will be by console) if you can cd in this directory. Please add here your ls of this directory for check permissions:

```
ls -la /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gamejutsu/www/img/avatars/
```

And if everything look good try change your console user to webserver user (usually www-data) and try acces to file

```
sudo su
su www-data
cat /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gamejutsu/www/img/avatars/Sonik_avatar.jpg
```

If you can acces to this file (it will be binary data) permissions are ok, in other case check if you have right permission to file and if you good owner and group of file.

Comment: Thank you for your input. var_dump(realpath($img_path)) returns me false. cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gamejutsu/www/img/avatars/ works so the path is good. But the permissions are not the same for all the file (though they have been uploaded the same way). Some have -rw-r--r-- and some have -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: And if you change permission manualy to (777) it works? It is weird because if you have read permission you can access to file via realpath and file_exists.. Did you try cd command with path from var_dump($img_path)? Plus i updated my answer

Comment: I tried to upload a new avatar and it has -rw-r--r--  . For this file I can have the real_path so I you seem to be right. I think the permissions have changed when I changed the application folder. However, I don't know how to change the permissions (i'm looking for it).

Comment: Permission can change by "chmod 777 /path/to/file"

Answer (score 0):

Try just use website root and do not use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

Comment: It does not solve the problem : Warning: unlink(/gamejutsu/www/img/avatars/Billy_avatar.jpg): No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gamejutsu/www/admin/members.php on line 67

Comment: Why should OP "try this" ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by identifying the path.

```
if($_POST['delete-avatar'] == 'on') {
    $q = execute_query("SELECT avatar FROM gj_customers WHERE id_customer = '$_GET[id]'");
    $customer = $q->fetch_assoc(); 
    $img_path =' filename' . WEBSITE_ROOT . $customer['avatar']; 
    var_dump($img_path);

    if(!empty($customer['avatar']) && file_exists($img_path)) {       
        unlink($img_path);
    }

}
```